# Try Catch block inside toString method

Tags: java, try-catch, tostring

Have `toString` standard method inside my class that overrides `Object` ones.

Is it good practice to use try catch in this method?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    try {
        return 
                "number='" + product.getProductNumber() + 
                ", locale=" + locale;
    } catch (ProductException e) {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: which method is throwing ProductException?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to to ask whether it is a "good practice", rather than "normal practice".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not normal practice. Exceptions should be used to handle exceptional situations, not the regular code flow.

Your code uses `try`/`catch` to detect situations that could be handled without introducing exceptions. It is roughly equivalent to the following method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if (product.checkProductNumber()) {
        return "number='" + product.getProductNumber() + 
               ", locale=" + locale;
    } else {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

The imaginary `checkProductNumber` method returns `true` when `getProductNumber` call would not throw `ProductException`, and `false` otherwise. Making a method like `checkProductNumber` and using it instead of catching the exception is a better way of coding methods where exceptions are caught during the normal program flow.

Answer (score 2):

Using Try/Catch in toString in not a normat practice but there is no restriction to use try/catch in toString method(). 
but if you want to remove try/catch in your code then you must have a knowledge that who throw this `ProductException` exception and what are the condition in which this exception is thrown.

- If this is checked exception then in that case you can create temp method with boolean option to check whether this operation will run normally or throw an exception. As shown in @dasblinkenlight answer.

Note: best practice says that toString() method is always overridden in those classess who contains some data and in those type of classes getter/setter is only used for getting and setting values so there is no chance of exception.
If you want to do some opertion on data then try to do that outside of the this class. Use these type of classes to only contains data and don't perform operation inside the class(except small operation only if extremly required)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious reason for not doing it like this. However your current proposal will loose the locale info if a ProductException is thrown. Unless you only want this OR the super.toString(), maybe you should do something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String number = null;
    try {
        number = product.getProductNumber();
    } catch (ProductException e) {
        number = "unknown: " + e.getMessage(); // or something like this
    }
    // here you may or may not include super.toString()
    return super.toString() + ", number=" + number + ", locale=" + locale;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the usage of try-catch in toString. But if you are using some method which can throw the exception then I dont see any issue in using try-catch inside of toString

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is nothing wrong with this.If you know that any exception will occur in `toString()` then you can use `try-catch{ }` in it.

Answer (score 0):

If The method `product.getProductNumber()` may throw the ProductException it is the right way.